# Need help vertically centering an item in the space left in a column

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have two columns.  The first column contains several items.  I want the last item to be vertically centered in the remaining empty space.

For example, if the left column was 4 inches high, contained 3 items,  and the first two items were taking up the top 2 inches, then the last item would be vertically centered in the bottom two inches.

To do this, I am trying to use FlexBox for the first time and failing miserably.  I am able to vertically center the whole left column (if I put align-items: center; under .row), but I cannot get it to work by putting align-items: center; under .lastitem.

```
.row {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 100%;
}

.column {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-basis: 100%;
    flex: 1;
}

.lastitem{
    align-items: center;
}
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Added: I'm sorry, I'm not sure how to just share the relevant code. Here is a link to the test page in question: njfilmschool.com/homenew4.php All I'm trying to do it make it so the "Laurel Image" is centered vertically below the Instagram feed and above the footer line. But because the page is generated dynamically that empty space changes size. It seems like FlexBox should let me do this, but what I'm doing is having no effect on the image.

Comment: Do you only want to use flexbox or open to other solutions as well?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow _ Please insert your HTML into the question as well _ This will make it more likely you get an answer that can help resolve your issue

Comment: @ManojKumar, I am open to other solutions.

Comment: @inputforcolor Sharing the HTML is tricky, because it's mostly generated dynamically through some PHP code.

Comment: @Chris Messineo you need to upload your html code.

Comment: On your webpage all you need to do is (1) add `display: flex` to `#Left`, and (2) add `margin: auto` to `.njfslaurel`. There's also a lot of unnecessary code you can remove, but it doesn't seem to be causing a problem.

Comment: @Michael_B Make that an answer.

Comment: @ManojKumar, this question is incomplete and off-topic. It's not helpful to future visitors as the problem can't be reproduced. I voted to close.

Comment: @Michael_B, Thanks so much - that did it!  I want to mark my question as solved, but it won't let me select your response as an answer.  How do I set this to closed?

Comment: If you can't make the question useful to the broader community (e.g., by posting enough code to reproduce the problem) then I would just delete it. If you cannot delete it, then the community will probably close it anyway.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @Michael_B, Honestly, I'm sorry if I did a bad job asking the question.  I do wish I could mark your response as an answer - as it really did solve my problem and I am so appreciative.  I will try to do better with my questions in the future.

Comment: No problem. Just keep in mind that this site is attempting to create valuable posts that can be referenced by developers well into the future. It's not intended to provide free assistance to individuals (although that's a healthy side effect). Just take a look at the guidelines. I'm happy I could assist you. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest you a flexbox solution if you are ready to show the whole code. Probably you are missing `display: flex` on the `.lastitem` and hence the `align-items: center` is not being rendered by the DOM.

At this moment, I have a nested [CSS Grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid) solution below:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr) 2fr; /* One inch - One Inch - Two Inch Inches are fractions here*/
  grid-column-gap: 10px;
  grid-row-gap: 10px;
  background: #6A67CE;
  padding: 15px;
}

.div1 {
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 2; /* Start at Row1, end at Row2, Start at Col1. end at Col2 */
}

.div2 {
  grid-area: 2 / 1 / 3 / 2;
}

.div3 {
  grid-area: 3 / 1 / 4 / 2;
  display: grid;
  /* Nested Grid */
  align-items: center;
}


/* Snippet styling */

.container > div {
  background: #5548B0;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 36px;
  padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="div1"> 1 </div>
  <div class="div2"> 2 </div>
  <div class="div3"> 3 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure how to just share the relevant code.  Here is a link to the test page in question: http://www.njfilmschool.com/homenew4.php All I'm trying to do it make it so the "Laurel Image" is centered vertically below the Instagram feed and above the footer line.  But because the page is generated dynamically that empty space changes size.  It seems like FlexBox should let me do this, but what I'm doing is having no effect on the image.

Comment: Check Michael's comment on your question.